# Regular expression for three numbers

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I created a regular expression that would match 2 numbers in any order from a four digit number. I am trying to create a regular expression that can math 3 numbers out of a four digit number in any order. Below is what I currently use to match two numbers:

```
regEx01 = re.compile(r'\b[0-9]*(?:0[0-9]*[0-9]?1|1[0-9]*[0-9]?0)[0-9]*\b')
```

Matches `0` and `1` in `7019`, `8019`, `2160`.

Future regular expression must match `0`, `1` and `2`.

```
7012 positive
0190 negative
9201 positive
1226 negative
```

Any direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex based on positive lookaheads to make it concise:

```
\b(?=\d*0)(?=\d*1)(?=\d*2)\d+\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NkMQmr/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?=\d*0)` - a positive lookahead that requires a `0` after zero or more digits
- `(?=\d*1)` - requires `1`
- `(?=\d*2)` - requires `2`
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\b` - word boundary

Or, to increase performance, replace `\d*`s with "subtracted" values:

```
r'\b(?=[1-9]*0)(?=[02-9]*1)(?=[013-9]*2)\d+\b'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NkMQmr/2)

Here, `(?=[1-9]*0)` quickly checks if there is a `0` after 0+ digits from `1` to `9`, `(?=[02-9]*1)` checks for `1` and `(?=[013-9]*2)` checks for `2` in a similar way.

Comment: Works like a charm.Thank you for your help!